# Shorten link but still resolve

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I am looking to be able to take the url.

```
  www.domain.com/dash/photo/site%20-%20desc%20location
```

and turn it into (and still resolve).

```
  www.domain.com/dash/photo/site
```

Not sure if this is possible with something like rewrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).  [Here](http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/) is a nice guide to rewriting urls.

In your .htaccess try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !%20-desc%20location

RewriteRule ^/site$ /site%20-desc%20location [L]
```

This is a very specific rewrite rule, and if you have other files that need changing, you will need to write a more complicated regex.

Comment: Only solution I can get to work is a 301 redirect.  Can mod_rewrite work with the first space?

Comment: mod_rewrite will take the requested url (i.e. the url in the top url bar) and silently rewrite it (i.e. not display the changes in the top url bar) so that it matches an actual file/directory.  The goal here is that you type/route to www.domain.com/dash/photo/site and have mod_rewrite change that url to www.domain.com/dash/photo/site%20-%20desc%20location without external redirection (301 redirect).  The only time it will externally redirect is if you explicitly tell it to with the [R=301] flag after the rewriterule